# javascript style if statement not being met

Tags: javascript, events, if-statement, listener

I'm having toruble with this function, it requires two clicks before the if statement is satisfied even though in the CSS the condition should be met. On the fist click, the console shows `triggered` but not `if state` on the second click it does show `if state` can anyone understand why the condition is not being met?

```
function searchShow() {
    console.log('started');
    document.getElementById('top_line_2a').addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('triggered')
      var searchClickIcon = document.getElementById('top_line_2a');
      var searchClick = document.getElementById('top_line_3');
      if(searchClick.style.height == '0em') {
        console.log('if state');
        //searchClick.style.display = 'block';
        searchClick.style.height = '3em';
        searchClickIcon.style.color = 'white';
        searchClickIcon.style.textShadow = '0px 0px 7px white';
        document.getElementsByClassName('search')[0].focus();
      } else {
        //searchClick.style.display = 'none';
        searchClick.style.height = '0em';
        searchClickIcon.style.color = 'rgba(255, 187, 61, 1)';
        searchClickIcon.style.textShadow = '';
      }
    })
    console.log('added');
  }
```

Comment: console.log `searchClick.style.height` and see what you get ?

Comment: The style properties are usually not exactly like you set them : they're interpreted. A simple solution is to keep the state in javascript (as a boolean for example, or a click counter).

Comment: Please, users, refrain from trivial edits that bring nothing. This prevents useful edits until we refuse yours.

Comment: Usually, height is a number (in pixels, but not stated), not something with units.

Comment: okay so when i console log it it just returns empty then the second time '0em'

Comment: @HarveyA.Ramer - plain javascript using `element.style` usually does return units.

Comment: @user3105607 - Try setting the style inline and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing ping-pong / toggle effects, try not to compare with attribute value directly. The zero height could be "0em", "0", or numeric 0. You could try normalizing the value for this one particular case:

```
if (parseInt(searchClick.style.height,10)==0) {
  // show the container
} else {
  // hide the container
}
```

A much more reliable way is to take advantage of the fact that every DOM element can be dynamically assigned new attributes. Since you already have a handle to the searchClick object:

```
if (searchClick.showing){
  searchClick.showing=null;
  // hide the container
} else {
  searchClick.showing=true;
  // show the container
}
```

"showing" is your own attribute. When you first click on it, the marker is not there, so it'll show the container (initially hidden). Then the showing flag is attached to it, so you can detect it in the next click. If your initial state is showing, then use a different flag to reverse the logic. This is a *sure fire* method to implement a toggle.

Comment: Wouldn't simply using a boolean for the if/else better? There is only 2 states in what he's trying to achieve. Triggered or Not Triggered. So saying if (!triggered){triggered = true;}else{triggered = false} would be much better and obviously... cleaner

Comment: Yes, modifying objects you don't own isn't a best practice. It's cleaner to enclose the boolean in a closure.

Comment: But what's the scope of this boolean variable? The "showing" flag IS a boolean variable that's attached to the DOM object, except that I have the habit of using "true or null" instead of "true or false". The absent state of this attribute is initially null/undefined, although it also evaluates to false. This is just a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the height. Use a variable instead.

```
var triggered = false;
function searchShow() {
  document.getElementById('top_line_2a').addEventListener('click', function() {
    //Do stuff
    if(!triggered) {
      triggered = true;
      //Do stuff
    } else {
      triggered = false;
      //Do stuff
    }
  })
}
```

Checking for a style in an if statement isn't a good practice. If you ever change the size of your container for X reason, you'll also have to change the if/else statement to fit the change. It also make the code that much less clear to whoever will read it. Always try to avoid using hardcoded numbers when you can use something more effective.